# RedirectFromLogin in Silverlight Login Page

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, security, authentication

I am busy writing a login page in Silverlight.

I am using an Authentication Service that processes the logins and I am also creating a custom Membership and Roles providers.

Everything is working but I need some assistance. I would like some advice on how to redirect the user to page they came from before they were pushed to the Login page. Basically I want the same behavior as the standard ASP.Net login.

I am fully aware of the differences between ASP and Silverlight regarding Client and Server side models.

I can do the navigation but I always lose the session and cookie when I perform HtmlPage.Window.Navigate() to the ReturnUrl...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loosing session was because of this issue:
[Help with Authentication ASP.Net Service loses Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601258/help-with-authentication-asp-net-service-loses-login)