# Help with Authentication ASP.Net Service loses Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, authentication

I have been making use of the WCF Authentication Service in ASP.Net but I have found that whenever you navigate all session, user, login data is lost.

I have tested using the Standard ASP.Net Login page and mechanism and everything works fine...

Why is nothing persisting from one page to another?

Comment: No-one? I really need some assistance here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was hosting my pages in IIS and was navigating to localhost but the cookie for WCF based authentication was being created on the fully qualified external site name (mycomputer.ourdomain.org).